# Ionic keep app open in background

Tags: android, ionic3

I'm having an issue with one of my ionic apps where on android it closes completely after about an hour or so in the background, forcing the user to have to wait for the entire app to reload when they try to open it.

I attempted to use [this plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/) to solve the issue, but when running a debug version of the apk I get a warning that the app is "doing heavy tasks" in the background.  I don't want to drain my user's battery, but I need some way to prevent the users from having to reload the app completely after an hour or so since the initial app load can be a little slow.  What would be the best way to go about achieving this?

Comment: What is the app doing in the background? It's hard to advise if we don't know what kind of operations are going on.

Comment: The app won't be doing any work in the background, I just want to prevent it from closing so that user's don't have to reload the entire app everytime they open it, and resume from where they left off.

Comment: You can't really do much about it, the loading time in ionic is extremely long.